# How can I write this regex to get multiline data and convert to JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, excel

I have some data that I need to convert to an array, but I can't get the regex quite working. I just need a one dimensional array, don't need the numbers, just the values - but the items with line breaks is messing it up.

Regex: `([0-9]\-\ )(.*)([\s]*)`

Test: https://regex101.com/r/F9UIG8/1

Data:

```
1- TEST DATA.
   1- TEST DATA THAT GOES ONTO
      TWO LINES.
   2- MORE TESTS.
      1- ADDITIONAL MULTILINE 
         DATA WITH 
         SEVERAL LINES
   3- MORE TEST 3
   4- MORE TEST 4
      1- MORE SUB ITEMS
      2- SUB ITEM 2
      3- SUB ITEM MULTILINE
         SECOND LINE
      4- MORE
2- EVEN MORE TWO LINE
   SECOND LINE
   1- DATA
   2- DATA
   3- DATA
   4- DATA TWO LINE
      2ND LINE.
3- LAST BIT OF 2 LINE DATA
   WITH SECOND LINE
```

Comment: The standard suggestion here would be to use a JSON parser, not regex. Regex is inherently badly equipped to deal with JSON, since it is not a regular language.

Comment: @CAustin - Using a JSON parser would be a good suggestion if the source data were JSON, but clearly that isn't the case here.

Comment: @BrianRogers Sorry, I misread the question. I thought the data he posted represented his desired output.

Comment: @tsdexter - What programming language are you using?  It matters: different languages have differing implementations of Regex and therefore different capabilities.

Comment: @BrianRogers good point, thought I tagged javascript. I'm making an import script that will be javascript.. but right now the data exists in excel so I can use excel functions to convert each row into a JSON array or arrays or take it out of excel as a string and do it all in javascript

Comment: see my answer below for final solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46901062/786094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression with the `split()` method:

```
let text =  `1- TEST DATA.
   1- TEST DATA THAT GOES ONTO
      TWO LINES.
   2- MORE TESTS.
      1- ADDITIONAL MULTILINE
         DATA WITH
         SEVERAL LINES
   3- MORE TEST 3
   4- MORE TEST 4
      1- MORE SUB ITEMS
      2- SUB ITEM 2
      3- SUB ITEM MULTILINE
         SECOND LINE
      4- MORE
2- EVEN MORE TWO LINE
   SECOND LINE
   1- DATA
   2- DATA
   3- DATA
   4- DATA TWO LINE
      2ND LINE.
3- LAST BIT OF 2 LINE DATA`;

text.split(/\s*\d\-/igm);
```

It will return an array with the texts (including line breaks), removing the numbers and hypens.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance, I've built this into a google apps script using a variation of the answer from @ncardeli.

```
function JSONIFYRANGE(range, asJSON){
  var array = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    array.push({name: range[i][0], items: JSONIFY(range[i][1], asJSON)});
  }
  return JSON.stringify(array);
}

function JSONIFY(input, asJSON) {
  if(input.indexOf("[ ]") >= 0 || input.indexOf("[  ]") >= 0 || input.indexOf("[   ]") >= 0){
    return JSONIFY2(input, asJSON);
  } else {
    return JSONIFY1(input, asJSON);
  }
}

function JSONIFY1(input, asJSON) {
  var json = input.split(/\s*\d\-/igm); // answer from @ncardeli
  var newArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i] != "") {
      newArray.push(json[i].replace("SOME COMMON TEXT I DONT WANT IN THE ITEMS", "").trim());                
    }
  }
  return asJSON ? newArray : JSON.stringify(newArray);
}

function JSONIFY2(input, asJSON) {
  var json = input.split(/\s*\[\s*\]/igm);
  var newArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i] != "") {
      newArray.push(json[i].trim());
    }
  }
  return asJSON ? newArray : JSON.stringify(newArray);
}
```

Using it like: `=JSONIFYRANGE('Items'!B2:C40, true)` where B column holds the list name and C column holds the string to be split into items, outputs a JSON string with the following signature:

```
{[
  {
    name: "List 1 Name",
    items: [
      "TEST DATA THAT GOES INTO TWO LINES",
      "MORE TESTS.",
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "List 2 name",
    items: [
      "SOME ITEM",
      "SOME OTHER ITEM",
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]}
```